# adding markers in google maps API V3 from xml file

Tags: xml, google-maps-api-3, xmlhttprequest

i have problem on showing markers on google maps using xml file !!!

here is my xml file "exemple.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<markers>
<marker name="Pan Africa Market" address="1521 1st Ave, Seattle, WA" lat="47.608940"   lng="-122.340141" type="restaurant"/>
<marker name="Buddha Thai & Bar" address="2222 2nd Ave, Seattle, WA" lat="47.613590"  lng="-122.344391" type="bar"/>
<marker name="The Melting Pot" address="14 Mercer St, Seattle, WA" lat="47.624561" lng="-122.356445" type="restaurant"/>
<marker name="Ipanema Grill" address="1225 1st Ave, Seattle, WA" lat="47.606365" lng="-122.337654" type="restaurant"/>
<marker name="Sake House" address="2230 1st Ave, Seattle, WA" lat="47.612823" lng="-122.345673" type="bar"/>

<marker name="Crab Pot" address="1301 Alaskan Way, Seattle, WA" lat="47.605961" lng="-122.340363" type="restaurant"/>
<marker name="Mama's Mexican Kitchen" address="2234 2nd Ave, Seattle, WA" lat="47.613976" lng="-122.345467" type="bar"/>
<marker name="Wingdome" address="1416 E Olive Way, Seattle, WA" lat="47.617214" lng="-122.326584" type="bar"/>
<marker name="Piroshky Piroshky" address="1908 Pike pl, Seattle, WA" lat="47.610126" lng="-122.342834" type="restaurant"/>
</markers>
```

And the Html code is :

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>PHP/MySQL & Google Maps Example</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[

var customIcons = {
restaurant: {
icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png',
shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
},
bar: {
icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png',
shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
}
};

function load() {
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
center: new google.maps.LatLng(47.6145, -122.3418),
zoom: 13,
mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
});
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

// Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
downloadUrl("exemple.xml", function(data) {
var xml = data.responseXML;
var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
map: map,
position: point,
icon: icon.icon,
shadow: icon.shadow
});
bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
}
});
}

function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
infoWindow.setContent(html);
infoWindow.open(map, marker);
});
}

function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
new XMLHttpRequest;

request.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (request.readyState == 4) {
request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
callback(request, request.status);
}
};

request.open('GET', url, true);
request.send(null);
}

function doNothing() {}

//]]>

</script>

</head>

<body onload="load()">
<div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 300px"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

The map is well  created but without markers ... Thank you in advance for all you helps .

Comment: If you add console logging, can you find out what does your `markers` array look like?

Answer (score 1):

Reform your XML to the following example

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<markers>
  <marker>
     <name>Pan Africa Market</name>
     <address>1521 1st Ave, Seattle, WA</address>
     <lat>47.608940</lat>
     <lng>-122.340141</lng>
     <type>"restaurant"<type/>
  </marker>
  <marker>
    <...>Next marker info</...>
  </marker>
</markers>
```

Google Maps Api uses the XPost XML Format