# How to add markers to Google Maps from XML file in Android

Tags: android, xml, google-maps-markers

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18863507/8605376) answer, I've created a `XPost XML` of markers, as this is the format used by Google Maps API v3.

Here is the XML:

```
<markers>
   ...
   <marker>
      <name>Name</name>
      <address>Address</address>
      <lat>Lat</lat>
      <lng>Lng</lng>
      <type>G90</type>
      <status>A</status>
   </marker>
   ...
</markers>
```

Having this XML (as `String` for example), is there a quick method to add it in a `MapFragment` (`com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment`) or I have to "loop" the XML and add markers one by one?

Comment: Is this the unique format available? check the geojson format https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/utility/geojson

Comment: So you suggest me to use geojson instead of xpost xml. Can geojson be simply imported in `MapFragment` using `GeoJsonLayer`?

Comment: yes, look at the doc

Comment: I've used geojson and it works, thanks. So, there isn't any method to do it with XML, correct?

Comment: no, you have to parse your xml